# Do we need to create a new jar file for every change we make in our project

Tags: java, scala, jar, project

I'm somewhat new for these. I had done a project in Scala and created a JAR file for it. Now I want to do some changes in my project. So, do I need to create a new JAR file for every cycle of changes or is there any other way.

Comment: either you create a new, updated version of the same jar, or there is no reason to make changes. If you'll only use the jars with the older (unchanged) class files in it, you won't be able to use your changes anyway

Comment: Well think of it this way, you write a word document nd you print it, and then you modify the document. Do you expect the fiscal copy to change? - However, you may not need to create a new jar, like for running tests and running the app locally you can do all that through your build tool or IDE; but once the changes are ready to be deployed to production then yes you need to create a new JAR.

Comment: Tell ... if we are going to split hairs ... it is technically possible to update an existing JAR file (using `jar uf <jar-name> <files>` instead of creating a new one.  But you will need yo deploy the updated JAR ... so it makes not difference which way you do it.